# MERGE Nodes by a Property field

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have different nodes that share one same property field, i need to merge these nodes into one and in the same time copy all the rest of the other properties in the merge node.

example:

(n1,g,p1) (n2,g,p2) (n3,g,p3) =>(n,g,p1,p2,p3)

Important to Note that i don't need the `apoc` solutions since user defined functions  dosen't work in CAPS that i m working at

## update :

geohash is the field that have a repeated values, so i want to merge the nodes by this field .

The CAPS team gave me this cypher query to have distinct geohash nodes from the intial graph:

```
  CATALOG CREATE GRAPH temp {
    FROM GRAPH session.inputGraph
    MATCH (n)
    WITH DISTINCT n.geohash AS geohash
    CONSTRUCT 
    CREATE (:HashNode {geohash: geohash})
    RETURN GRAPH
   }
```

, however it still missing is the collect of the rest of the properties on the merged nodes.

I haven't a problem for the relationship ,cause we can copy them later from the intial graph:

```
 FROM GRAPH inputGraph
 MATCH (from)-[via]->(to)
 FROM GRAPH temp
 MATCH (n), (m)
 WHERE from.geohash = n. AND  AND to.geohash = m.geohash
 CONSTRUCT 
   CREATE (n)-[COPY OF via]->(m)
 RETURN GRAPH
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% possible in pure cypher, that's why there is an APOC procedure for that.

To merge two nodes , you have to :

- create the merge node with all the properties
- to create all the relationship of the nodes on the merge one

For the first part it's possible in cypher. Example :

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) IN [106, 68]
WITH collect(n) AS nodes
  CREATE (new:MyNode)
  with nodes, new
  UNWIND nodes as node
    SET new += properties(node)
    RETURN new
```

But for the second part, you need to be able to create relationship with a dynamic type and dynamic direction, and this is not allowed in cypher ...

Comment: the  first step is what i need, however the field that need to be merged isn't the id it is geohash field

Comment: This is just an example, you need to replace the first line what you need, the merging is done from the second line to the end.